# Check user registered during Woocommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, user-registration

I need to track user registration during the checkout (eg.: include tracking code on Thank You page).
When a user registers on the checkout page there is no clue about the registration inside the `$customer` or `$order` object as far as I know. Also, there is no query var to represent this.

How can I find out that a registration happened in the checkourt process? As an alternative, I'd be glad about any alternative tracking option for this.

I try to use the `woocommerce_thankyou` hook to check this.
Additionally, I am aware that the user logs in after the checkout in this case.

Comment: Try to find a different hook that is related to customer account creation (maybe `woocommerce_new_customer`), and check whether it is happening on the checkout page or elsewhere - and store that info in the session, so that you can then access it again in the thank you hook …?

Comment: @misorude somehow I missed your comment. This should be the best solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My own solution is not the most proper way but works.
Because registration during the checkout automatically logs in the user I can compare the registration date with the ThankYou page generation time. In this case If the user registered in the last 30 seconds the tracking code will be placed on the thank you page.

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'add_tracking_code_to_thankyou', 10, 1 );
function add_tracking_code_to_thankyou( $order_id ) {
    // Only for logged in users
    if ( $order_id && is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $udata = wp_get_current_user();
        $registered = new \DateTime($udata->user_registered);
        $current = new \DateTime();

        // get seconds elapsed after user registration
        $interval = $current->format('U') - $registered->format('U');

        if ($interval <= 30) {
            // echo 'tracking code';
        }
    }
}
```